# Доступ к элементу коллекции из подмассива строк

Tags: массивы, vb.net, коллекции

Есть коллекция и строка

```
Public teamCollections As New Collection
Dim testString(7) As String
```

Добавляю в нее статический массив строк.

```
teamCollections.Add(testString.Clone, increment)
```

Как можно ли получить доступ к Y-ой строке X-го элемента этой коллекции?
Пользуюсь коллекциями из-за возможности присвоить каждому массиву строк свой ключ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection поддерживает обращение по индексу:

```
Dim something As String = teamCollections(X)(Y)
```

Comment: Благодарю, элементарное оказывается, а я все пытался  teamCollections(x,y) и teamCollections(x{y}).

Answer (score 2):

Класс `Collection` является устаревшим, используй вместо него `Dictionary (Of TKey, TValue)` с соответствующими параметрами.

> X-го элемента этой коллекции

Что имеется в виду? Надеюсь, ключ, а не индекс?

> Синтаксис сильно не изменится все же.

Там не в синтаксисе дело. В словаре хранятся типизированные объекты. Им пользоваться намного удобнее. А Collection - это вообще из разряда подгонки под VB6 и, вероятно, жутко медленно работает, как и всё остальное из этой категории.

```
Dim Team As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
Team("Some Name") = {"Str 1", "Str 2"} ' Добавить или заменить элемент
Team.Add("Some Name", {"Str 1", "Str 2"}) ' Добавить новый элемент
```

Comment: Как ключ использую номер "тура", спасибо за совет. Синтаксис сильно не изменится все же.